# No debuggable processes

Tags: android, android-studio, out-of-memory

I am getting 'No debuggable processes' in android moniter. But I can run in a emulator. I am not sure what is the problem as it was working fine before. Getting following error :

```
Error:UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
Error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Error:Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

- Tried - Restart Android Studio ( preferably with invalidated caches as well ),Restart phone,Deactivate and reactivate usb debugging
- multiDexEnabling: multiDexEnabled true   and
     compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

Answer (score 0):

The heap limit of the dexing operation. Add this to your Android closure in your build.gradle file:

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

or use

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
}
```

Comment: Still not wokring. Getting following error. Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
Error:Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: can we see your  build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your App of debug version instead of a release one?
Click the "Build Variants" in the left bottom corner of you Android Studio and check the "Build Variant" column to make sure.